# Programatically attach current debugger to started processes

Tags: c#, debugging, process

One project I work on starts local processes during testing. Among other things it starts an instance of IISExpress running a .NET website.

I can debug the website code by manually attaching the debugger to the IISExpress process. However, I'd like to automate this manual step.

Below is the code I have so far. It does seem to find the process to attach to (i.e. `Attach2` is called). However the break points in the web site code are still not getting hit even after `Attach2` is called (they show up as a red circle with white fill).

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DebuggerHelper
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

    public static bool TryAttachProcessesToVisualStudioDebuggingCurrentProcess(params int[] processIds)
    {
        var notAttached = processIds.Length;
        var currentProcessId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

        IBindCtx bindCtx = null;
        IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable = null;
        IEnumMoniker enumMonikers = null;

        try
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx));
            bindCtx.GetRunningObjectTable(out runningObjectTable);
            runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out enumMonikers);
            enumMonikers.Reset();

            var numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
            var monikers = new IMoniker[1];
            while (enumMonikers.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
            {
                monikers[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out var runningObjectName);
                runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out var runningObjectVal);

                if (runningObjectVal is EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte
                    && runningObjectName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio.DTE.15.0"))
                {
                    foreach (EnvDTE80.Process2 debuggedProcess in dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses)
                    {
                        if (debuggedProcess.ProcessID == currentProcessId)
                        {
                            foreach (EnvDTE80.Process2 localProcess in dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses)
                            {
                                if (processIds.Contains(localProcess.ProcessID))
                                {
                                    localProcess.Attach();
                                    notAttached--;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return notAttached == 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (enumMonikers != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(enumMonikers);
            }

            if (runningObjectTable != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(runningObjectTable);
            }

            if (bindCtx != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Seems like it somewhat attached but something is failing. I'm getting the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the debugger was attaching to IISExpress as a native process instead of a managed one. After changing the code to instead use `Attach2` with managed specified it works as expected.

Updated working code (some of the other changes are probably unneeded and only a result of the troubleshooting process):

```
public class DebugHelper
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

    public static bool AttachTo(params int[] processIds)
    {
        var notAttached = processIds.Length;
        var maybeDebuggedProcessId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

        IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable = null;
        IEnumMoniker enumMoniker = null;
        IBindCtx bindCtx = null;

        try
        {
            CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
            GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
            runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out enumMoniker);

            var monikers = new IMoniker[1];
            var numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
            while (enumMoniker.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
            {
                monikers[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out var runningObjectName);
                runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out var runningObjectVal);

                if (runningObjectVal is DTE2 dte
                    && dte.Debugger is Debugger2 debugger
                    && runningObjectName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio.DTE.15.0"))
                {
                    foreach (Process2 debuggedProcess in dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses)
                    {
                        if (debuggedProcess.ProcessID == maybeDebuggedProcessId)
                        {
                            var def = debugger.Transports.Item("Default");
                            var engines = new List<Engine>();
                            foreach (Engine engine in def.Engines)
                            {
                                engines.Add(engine);
                            }

                            var debugEngine = new[]
                            {
                                engines.Single(x => x.Name == "Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0)")
                            };

                            foreach (Process2 localProcess in dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses)
                            {
                                if (processIds.Contains(localProcess.ProcessID))
                                {
                                    localProcess.Attach2(debugEngine);
                                    notAttached--;
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return notAttached == 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bindCtx != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
            if (runningObjectTable != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(runningObjectTable);
            if (enumMoniker != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(enumMoniker);
        }
    }
}
```